# CSV file to Json in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, csv, sankey-diagram

i have a question, i have a 'CSV file' data and it looks like this

```
source,xPos,target,xPos,value
user1,0,user2,1,4
user2,1,user3,2,4
user1,0,user3,2,2
user4,2
userA1,1,userA2,2,4
```

and I need to reform it, because my fuction uses a data set variable  with in this format which is in somehow a JSON format and it should look like :

```
{
"nodes":[
{"node":0,"name":"user1","xPos":0},
{"node":1,"name":"user2","xPos":1},
{"node":2,"name":"user3","xPos":2},
{"node":3,"name":"user4","xPos":2},
{"node":4,"name":"userA1","xPos":1}
{"node":5,"name":"userA2","xPos":2}
],
"links":[
{"source":0,"target":1,"value":4},
{"source":1,"target":2,"value":4},
{"source":0,"target":2,"value":2},
{"source":4,"target":5,"value":4}]
}
```

and the sources and targets are the node numbers that they are already predefined.

Is it possible to do that in javascript ?

Comment: Read up on loops, string splitting and concatenation in JavaScript; this is parsing text and output in another text format. Have you tried anything? What resources have you looked at? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the csv data by lines:

```
var lines = csvData.split("\n");
```

Then for each line split the line by comma (,)

```
var dataLine = lines[1].split(","); //not the 0th line as it has only the headers
```

Then loop `dataLine` with for or `forEach` and organize the data the way you want. Declare two json arrays one for `"links"` and other for `"nodes"`. Then assign your organized data to them.

And this is one of the way it is to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to do that in Javascript.

Comment: I was trying and searching but didnt find any hints @Pogrindis

Comment: Crazy right ? You just need some magic fairy dust, sprinkled on your laptop, or PC of course, then if you have any code (superfluous stuff right!), it will fix itself!

Comment: @Pogrindis :) Chris: here are a few useful functions : [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split lines and columns, [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build the desired object, [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to get a JSON string